# Windows XP/Ubuntu Dual Boot - Separate Drives - going straight to a GRUB prompt

Tags: boot, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Just installed Ubuntu for the first time. I have it on two separate drives. When I boot (from my main drive with the Windows XP install) it gives me two options:
-Windows
-Ubuntu

if I select Ubuntu and hit enter, it goes to GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.

If I change the boot drive to the one with Linux on it, it boots perfectly. BUT I don't want that, I'd like a dual boot option and I'd like to be able to access the content on my Windows Hard Drive.

Any tips on how to fix this? I tried boot repair (running through the auto steps) and it didn't help.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards the OP did not mention anything about a black screen issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your GRUB from first drive "chainloads" to  GRUB at second drive. Try [uninstalling GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131168/how-do-i-uninstall-grub) from second and run update-grub on first one.