How to install the bootloader to /dev/sda1 ( / ) instead /dev/sda in Ubuntu 24.04 on MBR disk?
How can the bootloader be installed to /dev/sda1 ( / ) instead of /dev/sda in Ubuntu 24.04 on MBR disk?
I don't see this option in the new installer.



Regards

That option should be available on the "custom install" option.

Are you installing in EFI mode or legacy mode?

Yes, I'm in the manual "custom" install. It's legacy mode.  I just added screenshots.

Usuallyit doesn't make much sense to install grub to a PBR instead of MBR. You might have a special reaso why you want do do so, we can't know. Obviously the installer does not give you the option do do so. You can change grub install location later in the installed system (sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc and remove the previously installed grub from MBR (https://askubuntu.com/a/131171/590937).

In installer 22.04 and earlier it was possible to install the bootloader to /. This made it possible to leave the MBR intact and boot to Ubuntu in a different way, e.g. using the Windows mechanism and EasyBCD with its useful functions.
In the case of Ubuntu 24.04, it seems that this option is not available. And thank you mook765, I will try to do as you suggest.

I have a similar issue... my main drive (SSD) is disabled as an option, the only option available is the USB drive from where I'm intalling Ubuntu 24.04... that doesn't make sense, the boot loader must be installed in the computer disk. Any help?

@Johny Your issue is different. And you should open your own question anyway instead of asking here in a comment.

Isn't there a dropdown Menu at the Button for choosing the place for the bootloader?
